# Issue in printing of flexbox row layout in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing, flexbox

I have simple row flexbox layout with one big column and 2 small ones, every browser prints it correctly as it looks in the browser, they just break page inside content of big column, but Firefox it seems can't do page break inside that big column as a result I have first page with content before columns (almost blank page) then I have cut content of columns on second page and content after on third page, here is my page:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 32%;
}
```

```html
<div>some stuff before</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    first column
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    second column
    <div>Aliqua Lorem laboris fugiat incididunt adipisicing eu duis. Culpa aliqua in sint cupidatat adipisicing mollit ad sit incididunt occaecat labore ea. Incididunt incididunt elit ad labore irure aliquip irure occaecat. Cupidatat cillum ipsum aliqua non
      laborum. Aliqua minim fugiat et nulla eiusmod.</div>
    <div>Aliqua Lorem laboris fugiat incididunt adipisicing eu duis. Culpa aliqua in sint cupidatat adipisicing mollit ad sit incididunt occaecat labore ea. Incididunt incididunt elit ad labore irure aliquip irure occaecat. Cupidatat cillum ipsum aliqua non
      laborum. Aliqua minim fugiat et nulla eiusmod.</div>
    <div>Aliqua Lorem laboris fugiat incididunt adipisicing eu duis. Culpa aliqua in sint cupidatat adipisicing mollit ad sit incididunt occaecat labore ea. Incididunt incididunt elit ad labore irure aliquip irure occaecat. Cupidatat cillum ipsum aliqua non
      laborum. Aliqua minim fugiat et nulla eiusmod.</div>
    <div>Aliqua Lorem laboris fugiat incididunt adipisicing eu duis. Culpa aliqua in sint cupidatat adipisicing mollit ad sit incididunt occaecat labore ea. Incididunt incididunt elit ad labore irure aliquip irure occaecat. Cupidatat cillum ipsum aliqua non
      laborum. Aliqua minim fugiat et nulla eiusmod.</div>
    <div>Aliqua Lorem laboris fugiat incididunt adipisicing eu duis. Culpa aliqua in sint cupidatat adipisicing mollit ad sit incididunt occaecat labore ea. Incididunt incididunt elit ad labore irure aliquip irure occaecat. Cupidatat cillum ipsum aliqua non
      laborum. Aliqua minim fugiat et nulla eiusmod.</div>
    <div>Aliqua Lorem laboris fugiat incididunt adipisicing eu duis. Culpa aliqua in sint cupidatat adipisicing mollit ad sit incididunt occaecat labore ea. Incididunt incididunt elit ad labore irure aliquip irure occaecat. Cupidatat cillum ipsum aliqua non
      laborum. Aliqua minim fugiat et nulla eiusmod.</div>
    <div>Aliqua Lorem laboris fugiat incididunt adipisicing eu duis. Culpa aliqua in sint cupidatat adipisicing mollit ad sit incididunt occaecat labore ea. Incididunt incididunt elit ad labore irure aliquip irure occaecat. Cupidatat cillum ipsum aliqua non
      laborum. Aliqua minim fugiat et nulla eiusmod.</div>
    <div>Aliqua Lorem laboris fugiat incididunt adipisicing eu duis. Culpa aliqua in sint cupidatat adipisicing mollit ad sit incididunt occaecat labore ea. Incididunt incididunt elit ad labore irure aliquip irure occaecat. Cupidatat cillum ipsum aliqua non
      laborum. Aliqua minim fugiat et nulla eiusmod.</div>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    third column
  </div>
</div>

<div>some stuff after</div>
```

**Update:**

some screenshots:

[firefox version (3 print pages)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUkFn.png)

[chrome and others browsers version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gur2e.png)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xnzqzdjm/1/ i've made a fiddle and i can't see anything different using firefox. Can you take some screenshots?

Comment: @sjahan I added screenshots, it is actually impossible to see that in fiddle, because you need send it to printing to see print pages breaks, but interestingly enough I don't see that behaviour when I'm trying to print [result of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnzqzdjm/embedded/result/#Result), but markup of cause is much different from mine